# Is there a way to trace the requested domains from a URL?

Tags: javascript, php, url, dns, trace

So the scenario is we have a server setup with OpenDNS, and we have Whitelist Only mode enabled, which will block all domains, regardless of your filter settings. Only the domains in the allow list is accessible. But if a user goes to, say, officedepot.com, there are other domains that will need to be whitelisted in order to fully permit access to officedepot.com.

I'm trying to write a tool for our system where we can drop a domain into a webpage and it will give me the sourced domains that are requested from the site. This is similar to Chrome's developer tools -> sources, where it gives you the list of requested domains. Is there a way in Javascript or PHP to trace these domains when using a root domain as the subject for the query?

I know the user can just go to developer tools, but these are non-techie groups.

Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: why do the other domains from officedepot.com need whitelisted?

Comment: Because in 'whitelist-only mode' it blocks all domain names, except what is listed in the allow list. So if officedepot.com references content from akamai.net, then akamai.net will be blocked unless it's saved in the allow list.

Comment: This problem is far more complicated then you think it is. There are many corner cases like iframes, subdomains and CDN's. Not to mention you would need to know all possible external resources the domain uses, across all pages, including those only accessible to logged in users. Even after you have solved all those problem, officedepot.com can still remove and add new external domains.

Comment: you need to allow a trusted client to momentarily unlock all the doors, make the request, log the side-effect connections going back to that client, and then save them for non-trusted users.

Comment: That certainly sounds like a better solution, but you still have to know all the domains being used across all pages, and then you have to keep on top of the whitelist. This entire thing sounds like a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score -1):

Just something that I found on Google, you should be able to get what you are wanting by changing this up a tad.

```
$pattern = '/<a[^>]+href="([^"]+)"[^"]*>/is';
$subject = file_get_contents($_GET['page']);
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $array);
print_r($array[1]);
```

Source: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/141828-solved-regex-link-grabber/

Comment: What if the page includes an `iframe` and that `iframe` includes other domains? This only considers a single page from a domain.

Comment: oh, very cool! I've been looking over Google as well, but just didn't know how to word the question, because I wasn't getting anywhere.

Comment: In that case it'd have to be looped and ran again using the link from where the iframe's content is gathered from.

Comment: forget about iframes, there's bigger issues: this ignores stylesheets imported from external stylesheets, doesn't hit scripts or background images, misses <audio> and <video>, etc...

Comment: @dandavis, this is true. To implement the solution this way requires a fully featured web crawler.